# Why is my code throwing "SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"?

Tags: javascript, loops, syntax-error

```
function listSquared(m, n){
    
  let ans = [];
   
  for (var i = m; i <= n; i++){
     let factors = [];
     let sum = 0;
    
     for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++){
       if (i % j == 0){
         factors.push(j);
       }
     } 
     for (var l = 0; l < factors.length; l++){
        sum += factors[l]**;
     }
     if (Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(sum))){
        ans.push([i, sum]);
     } 
  }
  
  return ans
}
```

Using this code I get an error message "SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" although each code block uses {} correctly. I'm just confused why this code doesn't run.

Comment: `factors[l]**;` you're missing the power on the right side of `**`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a term after the [`**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) operator on this line `sum += factors[l]**;`

Comment: ohhh thank you, i thought ** just automatically squared the number.

Comment: No it doesn't you can either use `** 2` or `Math.pow(..., 2)`